# Почему всегда threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() <= maximumPoolSize/2?

Tags: java, очередь-задач

Есть очередь задач, создана следующим образом:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(maximumPoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 50000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

Значение `maximumPoolSize` равно 200. Во время работы в `queue` попадает большое количество потоков (больше тысячи), но значение, возвращаемое методом `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` всегда меньше либо равно 100. Например, значения `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` и `queue.size()` логируются следующим образом:

```
logger.debug("Активные потоки: " + threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount() + ". В очереди " + queue.size() + " потоков.");
```

и в итоге мы получаем следующую картину:

```
Активные потоки: 1. В очереди 0 потоков.
Активные потоки: 2. В очереди 0 потоков.
Активные потоки: 3. В очереди 0 потоков.
Активные потоки: 4. В очереди 0 потоков.
Активные потоки: 5. В очереди 0 потоков.
...
Активные потоки: 86. В очереди 0 потоков.
Активные потоки: 87. В очереди 1 потоков.
Активные потоки: 88. В очереди 1 потоков.
Активные потоки: 89. В очереди 1 потоков.
Активные потоки: 90. В очереди 1 потоков.
...
Активные потоки: 99. В очереди 1 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 2 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 3 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 4 потоков.
...
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1874 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1875 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1876 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1877 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1878 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1879 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1880 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1881 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1882 потоков.
Активные потоки: 100. В очереди 1883 потоков.
```

В документации написано, что метод `threadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()` возвращает приблизительное количество потоков с активно выполняющимися задачами. Но почему максимальный порог этого приблизительного значения тут равен `maximumPoolSize`/2?

P.S. Это логи не с моего компьютера, у меня такую ситуацию воспроизвести не удалось - у меня в данном случае количество активных потоков равняется 200, как и ожидалось. Может ли это быть зависимость от количества процессоров/количества ядер процессоров/какой-либо конфигурации ПО?

Comment: Позволю себе оставить замечание, не имеющее отношение непосредственно к самому вопросу: в очередь скидываются не потоки, а задачи.

Comment: @Etki, cпасибо, это опечатка

Comment: Я думаю, есои вы не приведете полный код, очень мало шансов что вам кто-то ответит. У вас пул фиксированного размера, такой юзкейс описан в документации  `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Посмотрите [мини-бенчмарк](http://niklasschlimm.blogspot.ru/2012/03/threading-stories-about-robust-thread.html), который помогает определить оптимальный размер пула и очереди.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Есть очередь задач, создана следующим образом: ... new
>   ThreadPoolExecutor(maximumPoolSize, maximumPoolSize, .."

*Вы уверены, что maximumPoolSize - это одна переменная, и она имеет одно значение? Полагаю, что причина в том, что corePoolSize равен 100, а maximumPoolSize равен 200 и у Вас происходит следующее?*

При добавлении нового потока в пул выполняет следующие действия последовательно:

1. Проверяет достигнут ли предел потоков, задаваемых переменной
   corePoolSize если можно еще запустить поток - запускает его. Если
   количество потоков равно или больше corePoolSize переходит к
   следующему шагу.
2. Проверяет не заполнена ли очередь и если в ней еще есть место
   добавляет туда поток. Если очередь заполнена переходит к следующему
   шагу.
3. Пытается увеличить количество работающих потоков до значения
   maximumPoolSize если можно добавить еще поток, то он добавляется и в
   нем и запускается задание. Если количество работающих потоков равно
   maximumPoolSize то выбрасывается исключение
   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException или вызывается
   перехватчик отклонения задачи определяемый программистом.

В вашем случае в виду того, что очередь увеличивается без ограничений к третьему шагу алгоритм никогда не переходит. Но можно «изменить» порядок следования шагов 2 и 3. Для этого необходимо создать очередь в которой мы переопределим вызываемый `ThreadPoolExecutor` метод `offer` так, чтобы он возвращал всегда `false` (очередь заполнена). Теперь нам нужно задать собственный перехватчик `RejectedExecutionHandler`. В перехватчике мы добавляем полученный поток в очередь. Пример изложенного выше в виде кода:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue =
 new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> (100){
  public boolean offer(Runnable e) {return false;}
};

ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 200,
        1, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        queue,
        new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```